# Help finding an area relationship between n & 2n edges of a regular polygon inscribed in a circle in order to approximate Pi.

Tags: geometry

So I need help with a specific question on an assignment I have for university. First I will write down the question and then I will show what I've achieved so far.

> (a) Let $A_n$ denote the total area of a regular polygon, inscribed in a unit circle, with $n$ edges. Show that $$ 2 {\left( \frac{A_{2n}}{n} \right)}^2 = 1 - \sqrt{1 - {\left( \frac{2 A_n}{n} \right)}^2} \qquad n\geq 4 $$

Now in terms of what I have achieved, it's not much. I will use the image below as a reference. Now define $$\frac{A_n}{n} = Area(AEC), \qquad \frac{A_{2n}}{2n} = Area(ADC)$$ Then I find that $$\frac{A_{2n}}{2n} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{A_n}{n} + Area(BDC)$$ and this is where I get stuck. I have no idea how to find the area of BDC in terms of $A_n$.

I feel like it should be a lot easier but I just can't figure it out. Any guidance + help would be greatly appreciate. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You could use some basic trigonometry as you know the angle CDE, and the side lengths CD and DE.

Comment: It would also be useful to write the area of a regular polygon in a unit circle in terms of the number of sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'simplest' way is to just find a trigonometric formula for the area for each $n$, and then prove the desired identity just by substituting in the formula. It turns out to be nothing more than the double-angle formula.

But here is a direct non-trigonometric proof just for fun!

Note that all you need is $\dfrac{Area(\triangle ACD)}{Area(\triangle ABC)}$, which is just $\dfrac{|AD|}{|AB|}$. Let $x = |AB|$ and $y = |BC|$ and $a = Area(\triangle ACE)$. Then we want $\dfrac{A_{2n}}{n} = \dfrac{a}{x}$. We have $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and $xy = a$, and so $y^4-y^2+a^2 = 0$. Thus $\left( 1-2(\dfrac{A_{2n}}{n})^2 \right)^2 = (1-2y^2)^2 = 1 - 4(y^2-y^4) = 1 - 4a^2$. Taking square-roots yields the result because $y \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ since $n \ge 4$.

Note that without taking the square-root it holds even for $n = 3$.

Comment: @azza_075: Did you understand my answer? I think it's easier to obtain $Area(\triangle ACD)$ directly rather than $Area(\triangle BCD)$, whether or not you use trigonometry.

Comment: Yeah thanks heaps! Your approach was much better than mine :)

Comment: @azza_075: You're welcome! It took me quite a while to find the algebraic approach, so I think the trigonometric method is the intended one.